# Child objects not distributing in a LinearLayout where the Layout is bound to a ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a LinearLayout with three child components, I cannot get them to distribute evenly though, I've tried everything I've read so far, the layout is called as part of a binding to a ListView , all of the children are placed to the left of its' respective ListItem, regardless of what I do :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/runnerName"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="@style/RunnerListRunnerName"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/runnerOdds"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:gravity="center"
style="@style/RunnerListRunnerName"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/runnerDutchStake"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    style="@style/RunnerListRunnerName"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    />
```

I have also tried WeightSum=3 int the LinearLayout  but again it makes no impact to the child distribution : 
[image: Actual output]

Comment: I would guess that you're not inflating the layout correctly in your `Adapter`. That is, you're not passing the parent `ListView` in the `inflate()` call.

Comment: Down vote without a reason? Well that's helpful

Comment: Well, obviously I can't speak for why someone else would downvote you, but you really haven't provided enough information. That layout, on its own, will work as intended. I indicated that the problem might be in your `Adapter`, but you've not posted that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, I eventually found the answer. I agree that I did not provide enough information because the issue was in the parent ListView Item where this view is called as a ListItem.

The parent ListView Element had the Layout_width="wrap_content". I changed it to match_parent :

```
   <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="330dp"
            android:id="@+id/dutch_runner_list_view"
            style="@style/ListViewStyle"
            android:clickable="true" />
```

I found this interesting because it at least shows inherited style and heirarchy that was not immediately obvious.